# Is there any fast way to query average with itself excluded in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

For below table name: team_score

```
----------------------------
Team    score   date
----------------------------
A       1       2017-07-01 
B       2       2017-07-02
A       3       2017-07-02
B       4       2017-07-01
C       5       2017-07-02
C       6       2017-07-01
```

to get this table

```
-------------------------------------
team    avg     avg_excluding_itself 
-------------------------------------
A       2.0     4.25 
B       3.0     3.75 
C       5.5     2.50
```

what will be the most efficient way?

below query will not work as it is too resource consuming. imaging the table is 100GB in size.

```
select a.team, avg(a.score) as avg, avg(b.score) as avg_excluding_itself
from team_score a join team_score b on a.team <> b.team group by a.team
```

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that it will be resource consuming. Do share the results and also try performing an `EXPLAIN` on the query to help identify any issues with resource consumption.

Comment: 100GB?  Do you have the scores for all little-league games everywhere in the world?

Answer (score 0):

Two principles:

- An average is a sum divided by a count.
- "Excluding" can be computed by taking the entire total, minus what is to be excluded.

Yield:

```
SELECT
        team,
        ROUND(sum_me / count_me, 1) AS "Team's avg",
        ROUND((sum_all - sum_me) / (count_all - count_me), 2) AS "Avg of others"
    FROM ( SELECT team,
                  SUM(score) AS sum_me,
                  COUNT(*) AS count_me
               FROM team_score
               GROUP BY team ) AS me
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM(score) AS sum_all,
                  COUNT(*) AS count_all
               FROM team_score ) AS x   -- only one row
    GROUP BY team;
```

There will be two table scans, one for each subquery; this will to be too inefficient.